# Sorting a List of Lists to Group Characters and Minimize Adjacency Changes

Tags: python, sorting, optimization, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have a problem where I need to sort a list of lists containing an arbitrary number of 3 different characters ('A', 'B', and 'C'). Each inner list can have different lengths, ranging from one character to up to ten characters. The number of inner lists is dynamic and can range from 1 to 10 as well. My goal is to sort the list of lists in a way that minimized the number of adjacency changes. In other words, grouping the flattened list as much as possible.

For example, given the input list:
`[["A"],["B", "A", "A"],["B", "C", "B"],["C", "A"]]`

The flattened version is
`[A, B, A, A, B, C, B, C, A]`
Reading from left to right the characters change 7 times.

In this case, the desired output would be:
`[["A"],["A", "A", "B"],["B", "B", "C"],["C", "A"]]`
Where the characters change only 3 times when reading from left to right.

I am allowed to change the sequence in which the lists appear (which I did not do in the example), as well as the individual order within each list. However, I am not allowed to place characters outside their respective lists. The goal is to minimize the number of changes when flattening the 2D array.

I have attempted to solve this problem by greedily by selecting the next list resulting in the least amount of character changes and sorting that list in a fixed manner. However, this performs poorly in terms of efficiency and results

Could anyone suggest an algorithm or approach that efficiently solves this problem? I would greatly appreciate any insights into this problem. Thank you!

Comment: @KellyBundy The amount of characters in a list is a maximum of 10, the amount of inner lists can thus by anything op to 10. So, anything between all characters in one innerlist and all in a separate innerlist. The thing is, this operation is used to calculate a score for another optimization problem. Which means it happens every iteration. So therefore, it needs to be relatively fast, but also with good results. So searching the whole search space adds too much complexity. The example can easily be brute-forced but doing it for 10.000 iterations would take at least a day of brute forcing :)

Comment: @KellyBundy to literally answer your questions: Between 1 and 10 innerlists. 3 different characters

Comment: Can an inner list contain all three different characters, or only up to two like in your example?